# How to get an equation from a list of points in a python list?

Tags: python, equation, points, calculus

I've got an image filled with polygons, and a python script that draws borders around those polygons.  The polygons look like this:

[image]

Each border is drawn with a list of X,Y coordinates, which I have.  I'm told there is a general equation for a polygon, and I'd like to convert these points into an equation so I can then take the integral of it.  Is there a python module that can help with something like this?

Comment: Who were you told that by, and did they give any hints on how to determine it? I think the best you can do is approximate.

Comment: I'm going off of this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-there-an-equation-to-describe-regular-polygons